# Determine what caused LayoutUpdate/ArrangeOverride to occur?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom Panel which upon resizing has its LayoutUpdated event and ArrangeOverride called twice.

So initially MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride do their thing once upon open of the client window.  Then, if I maximize the window each are called twice.  The Available and Final Sizes respectively are not different between each iteration so I'm not sure what's initiating this.

Is there a way to determine the cause of the Invalidation?

Comment: I'm experiencing an issue that has be asking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577240/wpf-layoutupdated-event-firing-repeatedly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it is called twice because the Height and Width changes. I think that both of those properties affect Measure and thus there is a layout pass for each one.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to determine the cause of the Invalidation?

Invalidation usually is caused by a change of a DependencyProperty which among it's FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions has flags AffectsMeasure/AffectsOverride.

As Pavel already said - it's likely that invalidation fires for both changes in Width and Height.

Anyway, you shouldn't rely on the number of those invalidations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way is setting a breakpoint for each method and observing the call  stack. You will be able to see what happened before your method was called.

Comment: I'm not going to get a stack trace for that which invalidates the control.